# Getting value of local variable in Ghidra

Tags: disassembly, ghidra

I've been trying to solve a crackme challenge by examining it's decompiled version by Ghidra.
So I figured the code where the `strcmp` is done as shown in the figure below. Now I need to to patch the program to make it print the password if `strcmp` fails.

- The password is stored in `local_40`

But I don't know how to patch the instruction to print out the value at local_40

Instead of `MOV dword ptr [ESP],0x4b1050` what variable in this instruction should be edited? If my understanding is correct then the above instruction is loading the ESP register with the value at `0x4b1050`
so how will I get the address of `local_40`?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want to patch the program in order to discover the password? It would probably be easier to use a debugger or `ltrace` for this matter.

Comment: I'll resort to that if this didn't work, but just to learn this stuff, some help is appreciated

Comment: I'm guessing that you can try something like `LEA EAX, [EBP - 0x3c]; MOV dword ptr [ESP], EAX` (notice that `local_40` is actually `EBP - 0x3c`). You'll need to override some instructions before `0x40151a` as well, and therefore to point the `JNZ` accordingly.